# SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier in CREATE AS SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table from 2 other tables in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
CREATE TABLE share_stock(
  share_id    NUMBER(6,0), 
  share_price NUMBER(10,2),
  company_id  NUMBER(6,0), 
  company_name VARCHAR2(50), 
  ticker_symbol VARCHAR2(4),
AS SELECT share_price.share_price_id, share_price.price, share_price.company_id, company.name, company.ticker_symbol 
FROM share_price, company
WHERE share_price.company_id = company.company_id,
CONSTRAINT sh_pk PRIMARY KEY (share_price.share_price_id),
CONSTRAINT sh_pr_fk FOREIGN KEY (share_price.share_price_id) REFERENCES share_price(share_price_id)
);
```

Basically I am trying to perform a CREATE AS SELECT, but I am getting this error:

> Error at Command Line:294 Column:28 Error report: SQL Error:
>   ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

I have tried to correct my syntax and I have not managed to get it right so far,
Any ideas would be helpful,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've not worked with it, but the name of the feature suggests that it derives column information from the `SELECT` rather than you providing column definitions.

Comment: You cannot specify the columns like that in a `CREATE TABLE .. AS`. The column names and types are taken from the result of the select.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
CREATE TABLE share_stock
AS 
SELECT SP.share_price_id as share_id , 
       SP.price as share_price, SP.company_id, C.name, 
       C.ticker_symbol 
FROM share_price SP 
join company C on SP.company_id = C.company_id;

alter table share_stock
add CONSTRAINT sh_pk PRIMARY KEY (share_id);

alter table share_stock
add CONSTRAINT sh_pr_fk FOREIGN KEY (share_id) 
REFERENCES share_price(share_price_id);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked!
Could you explain why wasn't it working?

Comment: Your code doesn't work because it's not correct oracle's syntax. See this [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php). Don't forget to accept the answer to avoid low accepted rate and close the query. Also you can up vote ;).

Answer (score 0):

CONSTRAINT sh_pk PRIMARY KEY (**share_price.share_price_id**),
CONSTRAINT sh_pr_fk FOREIGN KEY (**share_price.**share_price_id) REFERENCES share_price(share_price_id)
);

Your code doesn't work because ORACLE doesn't know what is share_price.shareprice_id???
You should write share_id, that is the column you want to be a primary key for the table share_stock.

Kind regards,
MJ.

Comment: That is a wrong answer. The code is not working becase `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` doesn't support defining constraints (or any attribute of the table for that matter.